# Does macOS Photos have a QR code reader built in somehow, does it decode codes in images?

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app, metadata

I just imported a group of photos from my iPhone to Photos in macOS and the application "hiccuped" twice at the point where it read in two images of complicated QR-codes.

"hiccuped" = sort-of flashed another window that was too fast to see, or at least redrew the screen.

If Photos somehow detects a QR code and processes it to store the results for searching or indexing, I suppose that might explain it.

Photos 5.0, macOS 10.15.7

Comment: Were these QR code images regular photos of QR codes, or generated by QR Code tools? If they were generated, then that generation process is just as likely (compared to the content of the images) to have caused this

Comment: @EzekielElin they were just normal photos of a sign with a big paper QR code printout that took up about 1/3 of the area of the photo.

Comment: This seems like a yes / no question. Might you sharpen this with an edit if you want practical advice instead of people giving their opinion on a) performance b) how they might measure hiccups c) how the app works.

Comment: @bmike indeed it is a yes / no question. If that makes it off topic can you help point to the guidance in the help center or in meta where that was established and explained? To me it seems like an occasional yes / no question which can be answered isn't really going to cause harm the site. I'll also point out that if a question is off-topic one leaves a comment rather than writes a lengthy answer post going after the OP. In other fact-based SE if one doesn't yet understand the question one *asks for clarification in comments* rather than expounding on not understanding in an answer post.

Comment: What a great comment. I should have said, there’s no problem or ban on yes/no questions just that most people find them less useful. Plus, there’s always the exception to the rule where one is amazing. I just wanted to see if I could help further and it’s my shortcoming that I don’t get how to help with an answer. You’re all good.

Comment: Nobody outside Apple can answer „no“ to this because only Apple has access to the source code which would be required to prove a „no“. So unless other people experienced similar effects during imports, this might be hard to answer at all. Would you be able to share the images with the QR codes so others could try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @nohillside That's not necessarily true! I have no access to the source code, but I know that it can recognize faces *because I see it do that!*  Other ways to know what software does include reading literature from the distributor, and reviews of the software in independent publications. Yes, negatives are hard to prove, but positives are not. On the other hand "...others could try to reproduce the issue?" sounds like you would like to close the question because my question is about the product, not an issue with the product. In 18h (+24h grace period) bounty expires, and closing is easy.

Comment: @nohillside that would be fine. I suppose that I could contrive or manufacture an issue (e.g. "Can I sort my photos by QR codes?"), but that wouldn't be honest. I'm really just interested in knowing the answer. It seems like Apple would have some information available about what it does and doesn't extract from our photos locally, but Apple SE is not Apple, so maybe ask somewhere else. I suppose it could be a Security SE question, or Superuser...

Comment: "Recognizing faces" is a documented product feature, you are asking whether somebody can confirm the existence (or lack thereof) of an undocumented one. There might be other reasons for the behavior you noticed, one way to proceed with the analysis would be for others to try to load the same pictures and see what happens on their side. Actually, you could test this yourself by creating another user on your Mac, start Photos there and import these pictures again.

Comment: Also, "Can I sort my photos by QR codes?" is easy to answer actually: "There is no sort or filter option within Photos for QR codes, QR codes are not mentioned in the help pages/online manual either."

Comment: I’m voting to close my question because it's not likely to be answered (or answerable) in this site.

Comment: @nohillside I've started the close process, and bountied a question asking about [an actual problem I am facing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/465791/143729)

Answer (score 1):

QR code detection and reading does not involve any sort of "extra window", "screen redrawing" or the like. The fact that many QR code reader apps for example display photos with boxes in bright colors drawn on them, etc. does not mean that such display is actually a necessary part of the process.

I have never heard of Photos having a QR code scanning functionality. It does not use QR codes to index photos.

If you want to read QR codes with your iPhone, you can use the Camera app. It will by default detect and read QR codes.

Maybe you feel that the Photos app is hiding something from you, and that you suspect that QR-codes in your photos are getting "scanned" nefariously?

Your grounds for suspicion for that is that you saw something "flashing" or "redrawn" while importing photos. As mentioned above, QR-code scanning does not require any kind of on screen display, graphics or flashing of any kind.

It is most probably just a random occurence that Photos happened to be a bit slower changing from one photo to the other there. Scanning a QR-code in a photo can be done in milliseconds - it's not something that require Photos to pause between photos. In addition, indexing of photos for searching (i.e. the stuff Photos does to make it possible for you to search for locations, features in photos, etc. - as in for example searching for mountains or cat) happens in the background after photos have been imported.

In addition to this, what would Apple gain by "nefarisouly" scanning your photos for QR-codes - I cannot see anything. I guess you could search for "photos with QR-codes" in them - but besides that, what kind of secret feature would it be for? It simply doesn't make sense.

Yes, it is ofcourse possible that evil programmers at Apple hid a QR-code scanning feature in Photos that extracts all those very interesting QR-codes we all have lying around (like routing information on that UPS packages that was delivered 2 months ago, the link to that web page with video instructions on how to assemble the IKEA furniture you've bought last year, etc) - and seemingly not doing anything with that information. However, there's really no practical way of determining if that is the case.

You could conduct a very thorough analysis of the involved binaries, which includes a enormous code base of system frameworks.  It's not practical.

Comment: I haven't heard of Photos having a QR code functionality either, which is why I've asked here. Is there any way to confirm that  it does not use QR codes to index photos beyond "because I said so"? *Thanks!*

Comment: No, there's really no practical way of doing that. Can you explain why you're interested in it, it might be able to answer your question from a different angle?

Comment: Photos already has face recognition capabilities and can index by names of people who it thinks are in the photos, so there is nothing that would fundamentally prevent it from also having far simpler QR code decoding software as well. I'm just asking if it does.

Comment: I’m well aware that it easy to implement. The implementation is already in the framework that Photos uses. I’m asking why you want to know? … it doesn’t really make sense for Photos to do QR scanning without it being advertised.

Comment: "there's really no practical way of doing that" and "I’m well aware that it easy to implement" sort of cancel each other out, but that's okay. Anyway your answer is that you have not heard of it. And of course Apple has never put some functionality into its software that it didn't first fully advertise, right?

Comment: You have misunderstood me completely. It's really easy to implement QR-scanning of photos - I can do that in 5 minutes. That's not what you asked. You asked "Any way to confirm that it does not use QR codes to index photos" and I replied "There's really no practical way of doing that". Two different things.

Comment: I gather from what you're writing that you have some kind of distrust against Apple, that would feel that the Photos app is hiding something from you, and that you suspect that QR-codes in your photos are getting "scanned". Your only evidence for that is that you saw something "flashing" or "redrawn". I have explained to you that QR-code scanning does not require any kind of on screen display, graphics or flashing of any kind. It is most probably just a random occurence that Photos happened to be a bit slower changing from one photo to the other there. Scanning a QR-code in a photo can [...]

Comment: [...] be done in milliseconds - it's not something that require Photos to pause between photos. In addition, indexing of photos for searching (i.e. the stuff Photos does to make it possible for you to search for locations, features in photos, etc. - as in for example searching for mountains or cat) happens in the background after photos have been imported. In addition to this, what would Apple gain by "nefarisouly" scanning your photos for QR-codes - I cannot see anything. I guess you could search for "photos with QR-codes" in them - but besides that, what kind feature would it be for. [...]

Comment: [...] It simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh I see I've mis-assigned "it" and "that", got it. Let's just keep the focus on the question and not me personally. I saw a very quick "glitch" of some kind, it occurred at the moment the QR images were imported, I thought hmm.. maybe Photos does something when images with QR's are imported, so I'll ask in Apple SE to find out. It's not "evidence" and there is no trust/mistrust mentioned, you're creating a whole thing that's not there then going after it. I've flagged your answer because it's no longer about the question, it's targeting me.

Comment: I’m not targeting you - I’m trying to figure out what the question really is. The question isn’t “how can I search for QR codes in my photos” or “can I speed up Photos by disabling QR code scanning” - no, your question per your comments were specifically whether Apple added QR scanning secretly to Photos without disclosing it. I cannot see how answering that is “targeting you”, or why you would feel the need to flag the answer. Have I misunderstood what your question is about?

Comment: Did you check the console log wether there is an entry providing more detail?