# How to download all ECG reports to my laptop at once? Can I set it up for automatic future downloads?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-watch, data-transfer, health.app

The Health app on my iPhone SE-II iOS 16.4.1 has over 200 ECG measurements from my Apple Watch.

I would like to get them all on to my laptop (individual PDFs I assume?), but I would like to avoid selecting and downloading each, one-at-a-time style.

**update:** at six screen-touches per download, you can put on some music and do 200 in about 15 to 20 minutes (which I've just done) but I still think an answer will have value to future readers. I've added "*Can I set it up for automatic future downloads?*" to my question, which is still of keen interest to me.

Is there any way to "select all" and get all of them on to my laptop at the same time, so I can review them on the "big screen" and decide which ones to print?

Is there any way to set things up for future downloads to be automatic - either immediately, or perhaps once a day?

Comment: Well you can export all of your Health app data in one go and then trim it to get only the ECG data. I can explain if you're interested. The format of the export is XML.

Comment: @Thinkr Oh, that's interesting! Sure I would be very interested in seeing how to do that! I can look through the data with python scripts I assume, and then decide for which ones I really actually need the fancy PDFs printed. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 2):

While it is apparently not possible to download all ECG reports at once from the Health app, you can export the totality of your data present in the Health app in XML format (which is a common format for sharing data). The following is from [Share your data in Health on iPhone - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph5ede58c3d/ios):

> 1. Tap your picture or initials at the top right.
>    If you don’t see your picture or initials, tap Summary or Browse at the bottom of the screen, then scroll to the top of the screen.
> 2. Tap Export All Health Data, then choose a method for sharing your data.

Here's a screenshot of where the option is located:

[image: Screenshot of the Health 'account settings']

<sup>Click image for full size</sup>

---

In the "export" file once you've opened the zip's content, there is an entry called `InstantaneousBeatsPerMinute` which is part of the `HeartRateVariabilityMetadataList (InstantaneousBeatsPerMinute)`, this is where you'll find the ECG data.

Comment: Downloading all data is for sure the first step here, well spotted! Any idea how to extract the ECG data afterwards?

Comment: Yes! In the "export" file once you've opened the zip's content, there is an entry called "InstantaneousBeatsPerMinute" which is part of the "HeartRateVariabilityMetadataList (InstantaneousBeatsPerMinute)", this is where you'll find the ECG data.

Comment: *Thanks for your answer!* I'll give it a try soon and then accept your answer when I get it to work.